# Fail to execute "apktool if framework-res.apk"

Tags: android, apktool

I've updated the apktool to latest version(2.0.0-Beta9) , but it doesn't work.

```
▶ apktool if framework-res.apk 
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Multiple resources: spec=0x01030128 style/Theme.DeviceDefault, config=[DEFAULT]
    at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(ResConfig.java:63)
    at brut.androlib.res.data.ResConfig.addResource(ResConfig.java:56)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readEntry(ARSCDecoder.java:193)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readConfig(ARSCDecoder.java:162)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readType(ARSCDecoder.java:128)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readPackage(ARSCDecoder.java:103)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTable(ARSCDecoder.java:81)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:49)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:40)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.installFramework(AndrolibResources.java:675)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.installFramework(Androlib.java:641)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdInstallFramework(Main.java:252)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:91)
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I think this happens because I don't have the/a framework. I'm not even sure I really need a framework. More information about this would be very useful.